# Explanation for electrostatic energy expression

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electrostatics

My question is about the electrostatic energy $We$ expression for $n$ point charges. I just can't figure out where the factor "$\frac{1}{2}$" came from:

$We=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} q_iV_i$

Comment: Try writing this sum out for the case of two point-particles. Do you get the correct expression with the extra factor? Without the extra factor?

Answer (score 2):

The total energy can be expressed as the sum of the pairwise energys excluding the self-interaction energy.
$$W=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_iq_i\sum_{j\neq i}\frac{q_j}{r_{ij}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_iq_iV_i,$$
where $r_{ij}$ is the distance between two point charge. The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the fact that the summation term is symmetrical with respect to exchanging the indices $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Now I see! That's really true. I just couldn't figure it out in my head